# Check if the page is customized 404 in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna know whether the page is 404. The 404 error I mean is, Not shown by the browser but by the site itself - 'Customized 404 page'.
How to detect whether the page is 404.

[See this image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQeFSWhMafD1MnwimhQZW9vwrlXUpL-EeLN6w&usqp=CAU)

Click 'See this image' and see that image. That is 404 page of github and how can I detect whether the page is 404, like that.

I tried a lot for this but its not detecting whether its 404 page or not. Instead When I try with a 404 page which is shown by browser itself, it had detected but I don't know how to detect whether a site is 404 errored which has customized 404 error page.

Comment: Add a middleware after all expected middleware… if some requests reaches the last middleware then it is something not available… return your custom 404 error page there… if your application is a client side rendered / single page app, then you have to handle it in client router..but logic is same… last handler/middleware after all possible url is 404

Comment: How to check whether it is 404? Can you give me code in nodejs?

Comment: If you are using express js add app.use((req,res)=>{res.sendFilf(‘./404.html’)}); just before  calling create server instance..  if you are using raw http server add if to return all your valid content and return 404 html using res.sendFile inside the last else

Answer (score 0):

check url by checking `response error status` with axios GET call.

code

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const getTest = async (url) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            url,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

url = 'https://roine.github.com/p1'
getTest(url)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if(error.response.status == 404) {
            console.error(`This URL ${url} has 404 page`);
        }
    });
```

Simple version

```
const axios = require('axios')
url = 'https://roine.github.com/p1'
axios.get(url)
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status == 404) {
            console.error(`This URL ${url} has 404 page`);
        }
    });
```

Result

```
$ node test.js
This URL https://roine.github.com/p1 has 404 page
```

[image]